# Propagation of connectivity for level lines of a submersion

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $1\leq m\leq n$ integers and $\mathcal{O}$ an open connected set of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $f\in\mathcal{C}^1(\mathcal{O},\mathbb{R}^m)$, such that the differential of $f$ at any $x\in\mathcal{O}$ is surjective. Assume that for a certain $x_0\in\mathcal{O}$, the level line $f^{-1}\big(f\big(\{x_0\}\big)\big)$ is connected.

**Question:**  For any $x\in\mathcal{O}$, is the level line $f^{-1}\big(f\big(\{x\}\big)\big)$ connected?

Comment: As the given answer shows, this is false in general. However, it is true under the additional assumption that $f$ is proper.

Comment: $f$ proper in the sense that the inverse images of compact subsets are compact? So if $K\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is compact and connected and $f\in\mathcal{C}^1(K,\mathbb{R}^n)$, does the statement hold? If so, where is it possible to find a proof please?

Comment: Yes, proper in that sense. As I have it in mind, you want to assume the domain is a smooth manifold and the map is a proper smooth submersion, then it is in fact a fiber bundle by [Ehresmann's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehresmann's_lemma) and the claim follows. I don't care about things that aren't smooth, but you can probably check the theorem still holds for $C^2$ functions (maybe even $C^1$, but I don't know).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Let $\mathcal{O} = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2, y > 0 \}$ and $f \colon \mathcal{O} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $f(x,y) = x^2 - y^2$. For $(0,1) \in \mathcal{O} $, the level set
$$ f^{-1} \left( f((0,1)) \right) = f^{-1} ( \{ -1 \}) = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \, | \, x^2 - y^2 = -1, y > 0 \} = \{ (x, \sqrt{x^2 + 1}) \, | \, x \in \mathbb{R} \} $$

is connected while for $(1,1) \in \mathcal{O}$, the level set

$$ f^{-1} \left( f((1,1)) \right) = f^{-1} ( \{ 0 \}) = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \, | \, x^2 - y^2 = 0, y > 0 \} = \{ (x,x) \, | \, x > 0 
\} \cup \{ (x,-x) \, | \, x < 0 \} $$
is not connected.

---

For an example where the connectivity of the fibers isn't even preserved locally, take $\mathcal{O} = \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{ (x,y,0) \, | \, xy = 1 \}$ and $f \colon \mathcal{O} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ to be $f(x,y,z) = (y,z)$. For $(0,0,0) \in \mathcal{O}$, the level set

$$ f^{-1} \left( f \left( (0,0,0) \right) \right) = f^{-1} \left( \{ (0,0) \} \right) = \{ (x, 0, 0) \, | \, x \in \mathbb{R} \}$$
is connected but near $(0,0,0)$ you have points of the form $(\varepsilon, \varepsilon, 0)$ with $\varepsilon > 0$ and for them the level sets
$$ f^{-1} \left( f \left( (\varepsilon,\varepsilon,0) \right) \right) = f^{-1} \left( \{ (\varepsilon, 0) \} \right) = \left \{ (x,\varepsilon,0) \, | \, x \neq \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \right \}$$
are disconnected.

Comment: Your answer is very revelant for me. I have a weaker question: with the same assumptions, does there exist any open set $\mathcal{O)'\subset\mathcal{O}$ 
 such that $x_0\in\mathcal{O}'$ and such that for any $x\in\mathcal{O}'$, the level line $f^{-1}(\{f(x_0)\})$ is connected?

Comment: @GregoirePanel: No, this doesn't hold even locally. I've added an example. By the constant rank theorem, if you restrict $f$ to a small neighborhood, the fibers (in that small neighborhood) will be connected but the notion of a fiber is global while the notion of a submersion is local. Without some "global" conditions, you can't really expect from the fibers to stay connected.

Comment: @GregoirePanel: You are talking about the second example? Why not? We remove two curves from $\mathbb{R}^3$ (not $\mathbb{R}^2$) so the resulting set is still connected (even path connected). Given two points, you can always "bypass" the missing curves by going up and down.

Comment: If we now assume that $\mathcal{O}$ is convex, does the statement hold? Thank you for your enlighting answers.

Comment: @GregoirePanel: I doubt it, but I don't have the time to try and find a counterexample. Since an open convex set is diffeomorphic to the open unit ball, it is enough to find a counterexample for that case (or for a domain which is not necessarily convex but diffeomorphic to an open ball). You might want to ask your question separately to get some attention.